# Can laser diode be operated with lower than specified voltage?

Tags: voltage, diodes, laser

This is kind of a silly question, but please bear with me.

Could I operate a laser diode, which accepts an input of voltage of 5v according to specifications, with a 3.7v battery, just in order to get some sort of a beam out (doesn't need to be at full intensity)?

Answer (score 3):

First, you shouldn't be driving a laser with a fixed voltage, you should be using a constant current source. A fixed voltage source can easily damage a laser diode if the temperature changes and causes the I-V curve to drift up just a little bit.

Second, if you operate a laser diode below threshold (most likely, 5 V the maximum threshold voltage across all parts and operating conditions, and the actual threshold is somewhat lower) you will get vastly lower optical output. Furthermore, when operating sub-threshold a laser diode will behave more like an LED (much broader optical spectrum) than like a laser.

Comment: Although 5V is a very standard voltage for one of them cheap-ass metal cans with a built-in transistor circuit on the 1:100 feedback PD, so it may be it's at the bottom of its constant current at 3.7V in that case... though OP conveniently doesn't specify this is about a module rather than an actual diode. But I find 5V lasing threshold somewhat worrying if not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a random Laser Diode's data sheet, yes. Though probably not that great of a voltage difference. A Laser Diode is no different than any other diode (or diode pairs) when it comes to power. An increase in voltage leads to a increase in current. At a certain point, it will turn on, and increase exponentially until it burns itself out.

[image]

This one will turn on around 1.75 Volts, but won't be powerful until ~18 mA, which corresponds to 2 Volts. It's maximum will be 2.2 Volts, a very small change in voltage leading to a great increase in current, power, heat. *Heat which leads to an increase in current draw*. **A vicious cycle**. It needs to be ***current regulated*** or it will burn itself out.

A diode that needs 5V for it's stated recommended current/power, will likely not turn on at 3.7V, from experience. ***Check your diode's data sheet for actual numbers.***

Comment: Notice if you run your example device on fixed voltage, there is a possibility of thermal runaway. If temperature increases, then current increases. Which will cause more self-heating, which will cause higher current, possibly until the magic smoke is released.

Comment: @ThePhoton noted